# What is the “effet des machines”?

Tags: sens, science, physique

The book by Coriolis *Du calcul de l'effet des machines* is usually translated in English literally: “Calculation of the **Effect** of Machines”.

Is it possible to stretch the translation to “efficiency” or “effectiveness” without forcing the original French meaning?

Larousse gives an example: *être sans effet* : *rester* OU *demeurer sans effet* (to have no effect, to be **ineffective**).

That encouraged me to ask: what is the best word in English in your opinion? What is the exact meaning in French?

Update after the answers:
If you read wiki about it, Coriolis defined the new unit of work that would after be called Joule, substituting the British HP.

So what he did was to provide a unit of measurement of the output of a steam machine, as compared to real horses. What about “**performance**”?

> What about **output** ? –  mannaia

Thanks for your wonderful response, I am not able to judge if this option is acceptable, but I wanted to submit an element to your reflection:

Coriolis was just following ins Watt's steps, providing a measurement of the '*effect*-iveness- of a steam engine as a substitute of the work done by horses. Could you help you find the right contemporary term, just thinking of which word you would use for a horse? I imagine that even in old French you would not talk about the '*effet des chevaux*?

Comment: Performance somewhat imply you are comparing the effect with some others. *Effet* does not.

Comment: What about _output_ ?

Answer (score 3):

Translating *effet* by “efficiency” or “effectiveness” would narrow down the meaning somewhat. Efficiency and effectiveness relate to the quantification of useful consequences resulting from the use of the machine, relative to the effort that went into making the machine work. *Effet* in French, like *effect* in English, more broadly covers the consequences resulting from the use of the machine as a whole.

In the [preface by Navier, Girard and de Prony](https://archive.org/stream/ducalculdeleffe00corigoog#page/n9/mode/2up/search/effet), I think *effet* means what physicists today call [work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)) (*travail*, which is the term introduced by Coriolis in this very book and used by physicists today).

While effectiveness is basically work divided by input energy, this is a social consideration in that only certain effects are considered useful. Coriolis's book is about physics, and analyses physical measurements: work, energy, etc. I would say that *effect* is as effective a translation as any, and *efficiency* or *effectiveness* would be wrong — if the author had meant to write *efficacité* in French, he could have done so.

If you need to choose a word in a language that isn't etymologically related to French, the gist of the word *effet* is, what happens when the machine is used. It doesn't carry any implication of usefulness. A secondary consideration for translation would be to tie the use of the word to physics vocabulary, but this is somewhat difficult: readers in Coriolis's time may have understood a physical meaning of the word *effet*, but modern French readers don't, so even a translation into modern French would have to choose between respecting the everyday language meaning (so retain the word *effet*) and choosing a physical term (which could be *travail* [work] or possibly even *energie*). I would go for the everyday meaning, i.e. keep the title as it is.

Comment: @bobie I don't see how *performance* would be any better. You seem to be trying to write a different title, rather than trying to translate the title. In this case, [en] *effect* is a straightforward translation of [fr] *effet*, there is no false friend.

Comment: As you said, it was written 200 years ago in non-scientific terms, so that everybody would understand. Now, what is the nearest thing we can imagine to give it a physics sense, knowing what it really mean? isn't 'work' to far?

Comment: @bobie You use "work" in your ow question. And "work" is the word we learn in secondary-school physics. Wikipedia says, "The joule (/ˈdʒuːl/ or sometimes /ˈdʒaʊl/), symbol J, is a derived unit of **energy**, **work**, or amount of heat in the International System of Units."

Answer (score 1):

Both "Efficiency" or "effectiveness" add some kind of judgment of value (i.e. quality, performance) while the French "*Effet*" is neutral.

Both "*Effet*" and "Effect" are just about observing and measuring the results of what the "machine" produces without judging whether it is better than something else or not.

Answer (score 1):

**ADDED** Dec. 6 to try to address the OP's comment to my original response (see far below for my original, unedited response):

So it seems that you want a suitable synonym for « Effect » that wasn’t specifically used by physicists to describe machines and their power prior to Coriolis’ innovation.  Maybe that’s why Coriolis arrived at the seemingly curious choice of “Effet” because he didn’t want to be accused of using/borrowing a “better” word already used by his predecessors/competitors, and maybe it would be wise to accept/respect his choice and stick with “effect.’

But if you’re still searching, I would offer some final suggestions based on the “produire/to produce” sense of the word “effet”: “Ce qui est **produit** par une cause.”
So working with “to produce/product,” you could get to “the productivity of machines,” but like ‘Efficiency’ and ‘Effectiveness,’ ‘productivity’ could still imply a value judgment, although perhaps a bit less than the two “E” words.
To remain completely neutral using the “product” sense of “Effet,” you could perhaps use:

“the production capacity,” “the production capability,” or “the production potential” [of machines].

(Finally maybe adding “potential” before “productivity” [or even before “efficiency” or “effectiveness”] would help resolve the value judgment issue and retain neutrality in the translated title, i.e., “Calculation of the potential effectiveness/efficiency/productivity of machines.”)

**(Original Response)**

The more I read your question, the more I understand your desire to replace/"change" *effect* in the English title.
There's a meaning of *effet*, the French noun, that is "**puissance** transmise (par une force, **une machine**)" in my *Le Robert-Micro* and therefore, I think "**Power**" would be a suitable replacement that would convey in English both the (^)*effect* sense and the above *physics* sense conveyed by *effet* in the original French title.
(^)(*Effect* arguably could mean *Power* in the sense that:"She has an effect on me/She has a power over me)

(BTW, in checking the meaning of *puissance*, I actually found *force* and *efficacité* (!efficiency/effectiveness!) as synonyms under definition #3 (still in my Le Robert-Micro), but I agree with others that *efficiency/effectiveness* would be changing the meaning and adding a value judgment.  "Calculation of the **power** of machines," however, would seem to maintain the neutrality found in the French title [and it would work for horses, too!]).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you are right. But power is a definite physics unit and that is what Watt used and described. The innovation by Coriolis was to substitute that concept and unit of energy * second, the concept and unit of sheer energy, which at the time was expressed in Volt*Coulomb and after the 'Exposition Universelle' in 1889 was changed to Joule